# Styling specific background color for Elevated Button

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, material-design

I'm trying to design a Flutter `ElevatedButton` in the context of an app that follows a specific color palette designed by me.
Is there a way to style this button with a specific, hex entered, non material color (i.e. using a color through `MaterialStateProperty.all()` but specifying `Color(0x00170E04)` instead of `Colors.black`)?
I'm asking this because I tried many solutions, and the button color did not change in any of them, it just reset to the default blue color of `ElevatedButton`. I've come to think that colors different from the material ones cannot be used?

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:vudu_companion/dice_view.dart';

import '../blocs/dice_bloc.dart';

class DiceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DiceScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0x00170E04),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const Gap(100),
          const DiceView(),
          const Gap(20),
          // Buttons...
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: const Color(0x00170E04)
                ),
                  onPressed:
                      () => Future.delayed(
                          const Duration(seconds: 1),
                              () => context.read<DiceBloc>().add(RollDice())
                      ),
                  child: const Text('Lancia i dadi')
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => context.read<DiceBloc>().add(ResetDice()),
                child: const Text('Nuovo turno'),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      );
  }
}
```

And this is my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:vudu_companion/blocs/dice_bloc.dart';

import 'screens/dice_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(const VuduApp());

class VuduApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const VuduApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => DiceBloc()..add(RollDice()),
        child: const DiceScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ElevatedButton(
 style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: const Color(0xff032423)),
 child: const Text("OK"))
```

i think , maybe your problem is you use `0x00...`  which is , you set opacity to 0%
try to use `0xFF...` instead

https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/8710f6f752f6a0f2cae13abb538f0e8e#hex-opacity-values

Comment: Tried this too, the color doesn't change

Comment: It was such a stupid thing, I'm so sorry haha

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your hex color format is wrong, you should use `Color(0x00170E04)` instead of `Color(0x0x00170E04)`.
Try this:

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('click'),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0x00170E04)),
              ),
            )
```

And Try to Change your scaffold background to `Colors.white` to see the changes, because your scaffold background color and your button color are the same.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that was an error when writing the question, the format I used when coding was right

Comment: I already tried this, and the color just doesn't change.

Comment: could you please include your code where this doesn't work?

Comment: you said: *and the button color did not change in any of them*, this means you want apply this in one place and automatically changes apply to other ones?

Comment: Nope, in any of the attempts I made, such as your suggestion or the other answer's suggestion.

Comment: You expect to see what? the image I attach to my answer?

Comment: The button should change its color to the specified one., it should be a kind of black

Comment: the reason you can't see any thing is that your scaffold back ground is the same color as your button, try change the scaffold background color.

Comment: The other answer solved my problem, thanks anyway